# Combine multiple counts with group by including zeros

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I have 3 tables: Equipment, Sections and Users and i want to combine 3 tables grouped by section and show total equipment per section and total users per section including zeros

```
Example equipment table:


ID  Device Name    SectionID    Device Type
1   Holly's computer    1       PC
2   John's mobile       2       mobile
3   Maggie's printer    3       printer
4   Jonathan's scanner  3       scanner
5   George's scanner    2       scanner
6   Dugans handheld     5       scanner
7   Main printer        5       printer

Example sections table:
ID  Section
1   Finance
2   HR
3   IT
4   Manager
5   Storage

Example users table
ID  User         SectionID
1   John            3
2   George          2
3   Amanda          2
4   Andy            4
5   Katherine       1
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT 
b.section AS GROUPED_SECTION, 
COUNT(distinct a.sectionid) AS TOTAL_EQUIPMENT, 
COUNT(distinct c.sectionid) AS TOTAL_USERS 
FROM Equipment a 
LEFT JOIN Section b ON a.sectionid=b.id 
LEFT JOIN Users c on a.sectionid=c.sectionid 
GROUP BY b.description 
ORDER BY b.description
```

but something is not working correctly

I want to create a query that will have the following result:

```
SECTION        TOTAL_EQUIPMENT         TOTAL_USERS
-------        ---------------         ------------ 
Finance               1                     1 
IT                    2                     1
HR                    2                     2
Manager               0                     1
Storage               2                     0
```

-1st column presents distinct sections from Equipment table

-2nd column presents total equipment per section according to Equipment table

-3rd column presents total users under that section according to Users table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `UNION ALL` for `SectionID` on `equipment` and `users` tables. and make a `grp` column to split two different tables.

then do `OUTER JOIN` base on `sections` table, final use aggregate function get count.

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT s.Section,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN grp = 1 THEN 1 END) TOTAL_EQUIPMENT,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN grp = 2 THEN 1 END) TOTAL_USERS
FROM sections s 
LEFT JOIN (
  select SectionID,1 grp
  from equipment
  UNION ALL
  select SectionID,2 grp
  from users
) t1 on t1.SectionID = s.ID
GROUP BY s.Section
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4284f/9/0)**:

```
| Section | TOTAL_EQUIPMENT | TOTAL_USERS |
|---------|-----------------|-------------|
| Finance |               1 |           1 |
|      HR |               2 |           2 |
|      IT |               2 |           1 |
| Manager |               0 |           1 |
| Storage |               2 |           0 |
```

Answer (score 0):

The query is straightforward with CTE, count each of the two child tables, then join them to parent table (section)

Live test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f9f99/4

```
with eq as
(
  select sectionid, count(*) as total_equipment
  from equipment 
  group by sectionid
  )
, uq  as
(
  select sectionid, count(*) as total_users
  from users
  group by sectionid
  )
 select s.id, s.section, 
   total_equipment = isnull(eq.total_equipment, 0), 
   total_users = isnull(uq.total_users, 0)
 from sections s
 left join eq on s.id = eq.sectionid 
 left join uq on s.id = uq.sectionid
 order by s.section
```

Output:

```
| id | section | total_equipment | total_users |
|----|---------|-----------------|-------------|
|  1 | Finance |               1 |           1 |
|  2 |      HR |               2 |           2 |
|  3 |      IT |               2 |           1 |
|  4 | Manager |               0 |           1 |
|  5 | Storage |               2 |           0 |
```